# Behavior of pass and break in multiple loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop, break

I'm very new to Python, and when following the tutorial, I decided to run a more complete script of factorization and prime number testing:

```
prim = []
comp = []
for i in range(2, 101):
  for n in range(2, i//2 + 1):
    if i % n == 0:
      if n <= i//n:
        print(i, 'is equal to', n, '*', i//n)
        if not i in comp:
          comp.append(i)
      else:
        break
  else:
    print(i, 'is a prime number')
    prim.append(i)
```

It is supposed to store the prime numbers and the composite numbers in lists called `prim` and `comp` respectively, prints `xxx is a prime number` for prime numbers, and prints only the unique factorization for composite numbers, such as:

```
30 is equal to 2 * 15
30 is equal to 3 * 10
30 is equal to 5 * 6
```

The code runs successfully and seems to work, but then I noticed that for square numbers of prime numbers (namely, 4, 9, 25, and 49), it is both factorized *and* shown as a prime number, which is clearly wrong. After a bit of trial and error, I came up with the following code:

```
prim = []
comp = []
for i in range(2, 101):
  for n in range(2, i//2 + 1):
    if i % n == 0:
      if n <= i//n:
        print(i, 'is equal to', n, '*', i//n)
        if not i in comp:
          comp.append(i)
      else:
        pass
      break
  else:
    print(i, 'is a prime number')
    prim.append(i)
```

And it now works correctly as intended. However, I understand neither why I got it wrong before nor how I got it right now. I know it has something to do with the level I use `break`, but as I'm just beginning to grasp the way Python syntax handles loops and flow controls, I'm not yet able to pinpoint the problem. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: You can drop the `else: pass` lines altogether; `pass` is nothing but a no-op, a statement you can use if an indented block is required. Here it isn't, because `else` is optional.

Comment: `continue` is another keyword you may want to familiarize yourself with

Comment: i think I found out what the problem was: do I just answer my own question, or should I wait for a while longer instead?